# VSTS - Where has 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' gone?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have VSTS builds that use the Powershell script to access the VSTS API, similar to that detailed in [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts).

The document states:

> To enable your script to use the build process OAuth token, go to the Options tab of the build definition and select Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token.
>
> After you've done that, your script can use to SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
>   environment variable to access the VSTS REST API. For example:

Example:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build-release/definitions/$($env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=2.0"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Definition = $($definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1000)"
```

As detailed in Microsofts Documentation, I'm sure you used to go to Build > Options and click 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token', but it is no longer there (see pic below).

[image]

When I try a build I get the following (which doesn't happen for my old builds):

> Invoke-RestMethod :
>   {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user '' is
>   not authorized to access this

In addition, when I clone a build (which worked nicely when I did it 3 months ago), the property is set to false (it's set to true on the original).

[image]

UPDATE: If I export from VSTS, change that property and import again, it works, but I really need a solution without this sort of manual intervention.

How should this be done now please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is available in the agent phase now

[image]