# How to add test result file to vtsts build using custom build task extension

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

- I have now a custom build task extension that I created.
- I added the build task to my build definition.
- In the build task I create some result file.
- **How can I add that file as a test result in the current build.**
- Is there API, to upload a file, get current account name, and needed authentication information, get current build number, project name, etc

I'm totally new to VSTS and online resources doesn't help much from where should I start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API in VSTS supports [updating a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/update%20build?view=vsts-rest-4.1). You can use PAT (Personal Access Token) to authenticate with the VSTS REST API. But if you are running script with build to access REST API you can just enable "[Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741682/vsts-where-has-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-gone/50743846#50743846)"
You can use PowerShell and invoke a request to update many things in VSTS using rest API (use PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod). To get the current build number etc. within a build you can use [build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch) as shown below.

```
$collectionUri = $Env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
$TeamProject = $Env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT
$BuildName = $Env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME
$BuildId = $Env:BUILD_BUILDID
$BuildNumber = $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
```