# VSTS-Authentication with TFS Server failed. Please check your settings. TFS agent error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]Two builds runs successfully using triggers but the third build faild on trigger and give error "Authentication with TFS Server failed. Please check your settings."? any solution?

Comment: What authentication method do you use (PAT, Basic)?

Comment: Yes is used Personal Access token

Comment: @AbidAli Are you are TFS or VSTS? look like VSTS from your Image

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue every time?

Answer (score 0):

As the message says just above the error you have to enable ['Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741682/vsts-where-has-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-gone) in the  build definition. It is possible to use a personal access token (PAT)to enable access to if you are triggering via PowerShell script or still you can rely on 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token'

Answer (score 0):

This is an Authentication issue, the message explicitly pointed out the troubleshooting options:

> - If you use the **OAuth Token**, make sure you enabled the access to it on    the Build Definition (Which mentioned in @ChamindaC's answer above : enable "[Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api)" in the build definition.).
> - **If you use a Personal Access Token, make sure it did not expire.**
> - If you use Basic Authorization, make sure alternate credentials are    enabled on your TFS/VSTS

Based on your comments, seems you are using PAT, then just to check if the PAT is expired or not, or just try adding a new PAT, then try it again with the new PAT.