# 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' must be enabled

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Can anybody explain me how to get this working?
I have a pipeline which uses a job template and that uses a steps template.

I can set the variable

```
variables:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

or

```
variables:
      system_accesstoken: $(System.AccessToken)
```

in the starting pipeline and in the steps template but it doesn't work.
([according to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837980/how-to-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-from-yaml-builds))

I keep getting:

> ### [error]'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' must be enabled.

If I set it through the visual designer and view the yaml or export the pipeline, I don't find any reference to setting `'Allow OAuth...'`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741682/vsts-where-has-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-gone) is also not helpful for a yaml based pipeline...

This is the task that needs the token:

```
- task: bool.fetch-build-artifact.fetch-build-artifact-task.fetch-build-artifact@3
    displayName: 'Fetch'
    inputs:
      project: '[omitted]'
      buildDefinitionId: 159
      artifactName: drop.develop
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to check if you're using
`- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0`
 and **not**
`bool.fetch-build-artifact.fetch-build-artifact-task.fetch-build-artifact@3`

What I ended up using:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
    inputs:
      buildType: specific
      project: '[project GUID omitted here]'
      pipeline: 159
      artifactName: drop.develop
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```